# Merging PDF's with iTextSharp: javascript lost

Tags: javascript, c#, merge, itext

I have two forms pdf that I have to merge programmatically. These 2 documents have javascript embedded and buttons to switch texts between three different languages (french, german, italian). Plus they are plenty AcroForm formfields. There is a javascript function that detects the app language and displays the document in the general user interface language.

When I merge using pdfSmartCopy, the result is a pdf document displaying the three languages simultaneously. I've seen that there is no javascript anymore in the merged document. I've tried to add Javascript manually :

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, new FileStream(destFileName, FileMode.Create));
copy.SetMergeFields();
doc.Open();
foreach (PdfReader r in listPdfSource)
{
    copy.AddDocument(r);
    PdfAction action = PdfAction.JavaScript(r.JavaScript, copy);
    copy.AddJavaScript(action);
}
doc.Close();
```

But the document still displays the three languages and the buttons don't work.
I've tried to look for XFA part but there is none.
Is there a way to keep the js functionnalities of the original documents and inject them in the merged result?

**EDIT**

Thank you for the OCG tip.
I've tried the following :

```
Dictionary<string, PdfLayer> layers = stamper.GetPdfLayers();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PdfLayer> layer in layers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(layer.Key);
}
```

And It gave me a very interesting list containing fre, ger, ita among other things. For a single original document I tested the way to "disable" a layer by using :

```
layer.On = false;
// or
layer.OnPanel = false;
// and
layer.View = false;
```

Only the third one gave a result.
Then I made the following:

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create));
copy.SetMergeFields();
doc.Open();
foreach (PdfReader r in listPdfSource)
{
    copy.AddDocument(r);
    PdfAction action = PdfAction.JavaScript(r.JavaScript, copy);
    copy.AddJavaScript(action);
}
doc.Close();
//re-open the document and create a stamper for getting the layers
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempFileName);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(destFileName, FileMode.Create));
stamper.GetPdfLayers()["ger"].View = false;
stamper.GetPdfLayers()["ita"].View = false;
stamper.Close();
```

But of course it doesn't work because the new document's layers list is empty!
It worked for a single original document. Then I tried to make this manipulation for each original document separately and merge them after. But it's still displaying the three languages simultaneously.

**EDIT 2**

I was asked by @Bruno Lowagie to share the original documents :

http://www.filedropper.com/source1

http://www.filedropper.com/source2

(I need a reputation of 10 to post more than 2 links? You can find the link for the merged document in the comments)

I really hope that a specialist can give me the way where to look further.
As I understood it's a question about OCG and JS involved at document level. How to retrieve and apply them to the new merged document.

Comment: Your original PDFs probably have optional content groups (OCGs). Can you share the PDFs? If not (and if you can't tell us if OCG is involved), please don't expect an answer.

Comment: First file :  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=97306123681013644715, second file : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=60578551726610465570

Comment: I hope this is appropriate. I've just googled "file hosting" and clicked on the first match.

Comment: Looking into the sample files I see that there is a combination of OCGs and JavaScript.

In the context of the task at hand, the internationalization, the former select the static document text, the latter change form fields.

Both of these techniques have elements defined at document-level, not page-level. As far as I know, therefore, `Pdf*Copy` won't copy these document-level elements, at least not by default. Here @Bruno might know some way to do this nonetheless.

Comment: In case of the JavaScript parts there is the additional challenge that both documents have document-level definitions of JavaScript functions with the same name but somewhat different content.

Furthermore both documents have form fields, some with the same name, some with different names, some of them referenced from the above mentioned JavaScript.

Comment: All in all, it is non-trivial to merge these documents correctly. In particular it is not clear what "*correctly*" shall mean: Shall the pages from the two source documents remain completely independent from each other? Or shall for example selecting a language using the controls on a page from the first source also change the language of the pages from the second source?

Comment: Thank you for taking time for this. The source documents have to be linked, non independant. I think that the source doc-level functions have to be the merged doc-level functions. Here you can dowload the document merged without layer modification.  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73995638946345181627 You can see that the same-named fields in the different pages act like they share the same value which is our goal. I thought it would be possible to "merge" the JS functions and inject them at the new document doc-level, so form fields stay referenced and share value and behavior.

Comment: *I thought it would be possible to "merge" the JS functions and inject them at the new document doc-level* - it may be possible but that definitively is not implemented in iTextSharp, so you must do that yourself. And that is not necessarily easy. If you have only a few documents to merge, merging the JS manually might be easier than trying to automate that task.

Comment: Referring the number of originals documents (4 or 5), I can do it manually. If it is not implemented, I have no idea how to proceed. Do you do it with RUPS?

Answer (score -1):

It might be worth checking out the following library:
http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx

Its free and it supports JS and HTML5, and you can bulk combine pdfs into one file. I have used it in the past to hide certain elements with JS for printing purposes .

Comment: As far as the page you linked says, that library supports JS in HTML to convert to PDF but not JS in PDFs to merge.

Comment: You are absolutely right, sorry I misread that and assumed that the pages where HTML in nature. After re-reading it, the link that I supplied would actually not benefit OP at all.